# Trying to compress avi file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, compression

I used the command below to compress an avi file(using ubuntu)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec msmpeg4v2 output.avi
```

but I am getting these errors

```
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[ac3 @ 0x9cd1fa0] invalid bit rate

Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect      
parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

What's wrong?

Comment: BTW: If you just in general want to compress a video file, msmpeg4v2 is a pretty bad choice. `ffmpeg -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -crf 23 -preset slower` is much better (change `-crf 23` to change the quality; lower = better quality. 18 is often considered visually lossless; you can go *much* higher). This encode will take a long time, even on fast hardware. Pick a different preset if its too slow. Also, if possible, use mkv or mp4 for the output format.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec msmpeg4v2 -acodec copy output.avi
```